# what is the equivalent of "ant -f" command in maven?

Tags: maven

I have an xml file called MakeJar.xml in the location ${basedir}/codebase. 
On my shell if I have to run that file i used to use the command "ant -f MakeJar.xml".
Now if I have to run this file using pom.xml how can I do that?

I prepared a following pom.xml. But it dosent work!!!

```
<plugin>        
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>        
<executions>          
<execution>            
 <id>default-cli</id>        
<goals>              
<goal>run</goal>            
</goals>            
<configuration>              
<tasks>


    <ant antfile="${basedir}/codebase/MakeJar.xml"/>
</tasks>            
</configuration>          
</execution>        
</executions>      
</plugin>
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) definition the attribute `antfile` is described as *"the buildfile to use. Defaults to "build.xml". This file is expected to be a filename relative to the dir attribute given."*

So you probably have to use:

```
<ant dir="${project.basedir}" antfile="codebase/MakeJar.xml" />
```

Also do not forget to specify a `<phase>` in the plugin section (is missing in your code). The following definition works for me:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <ant
                                dir="${project.basedir}"
                                antfile="codebase/MakeJar.xml" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\ptc\Windchill_10.1\Windchill\codebase\MakeJar.xml:98: taskdef class wt.tools.boot.ReadWTPropertyTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\ptc\Windchill_10.1\Windchill]
 around Ant part ...<ant antfile="codebase/MakeJar.xml" dir="C:\ptc\Windchill_10.1\Windchill"/>... @ 4:78 in C:\ptc\Windchill_10.1\Windchill\target\antrun\build-main.xml

Comment: Not sure what happens. Seems that you are missing some dependencies that are required for your ant build.